# A problem with Weirstrass substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I hope you all are doing well.

Yesterday, I was doing some undefined integral exercises when I faced an exercise that was something like:
$$\int \frac{F(\sin(x),\cos(x))}{G(\sin(x), \cos(x))}dx$$
I found that a substitution with $t =\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ would allow me to transform this integral in some $\int \frac{P(t)}{Q(t)}\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}dt$ using the following identities:
[image]

What I was wondering a few days ago, was that this identities had a problem when for example I express $\sin(x)$ as a $f(t)$ and $x = \pi$ (in this case $f(t)$ is not defined.). Also the fact that I make a $t =\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ restricts $\pi$ from the domain of the resulting $F(u)$ such that $F'(t) = f(t)$ so... What happens when I make a substitution $u = s(x)$ such that the domain of that function excludes some elements of the function I'm integrating? And also, what happens with the identities if $x = \pi$?

I hope to have expressed myself correctly. I do not speak english so feel free to improve my writing and sorry if there are grammar mistakes.

Thanks.

Comment: When making the substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$, you have to assume without loss of generality that $-\pi < x < \pi$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution)). The reason why you have to do this is quite subtle, but if you are interested in the details, I can elobrate. This means that division by zero is never an issue.

Comment: I would like, if it is not an issue, to find out why it is not a problem

Comment: Well, it is not a problem because if $-\pi < x < \pi$, then $\tan(x/2)$ is always defined, and so is $\sin(x/2)$. The hard part is justifying why we can (and should) assume that $-\pi < x < \pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose this substitution achieves $f(x)dx=g(t)dt$. For $a<\pi$,$$\int_a^\pi f(x)dx=\lim_{y\to\pi^-}\int_a^yf(x)dx=\lim_{y\to\pi^-}\int_{\tan(a/2)}^{\tan(y/2)}g(t)dt=\int_{\tan(a/2)}^\infty g(t)dt.$$You can treat [limits of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Terminology_and_notation) above $\pi$ with [one-sided limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) in a similar way: if $a>\pi$,$$\int_\pi^af(x)dx=\lim_{y\to\pi^+}\int_y^af(x)dx=\lim_{y\to\pi^+}\int_{\tan(y/2)}^{\tan(a/2)}g(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\tan(a/2)}g(t)dt.$$